# adding axioms to K logic

Tags: formal-proofs, modal-logic

Let $K$ be the modal logic extending classical propositional logic by adding the necessitation rule

**N**: if $\vdash A$, then $\vdash \square A$

and the distribution axiom

**K**: $\square(A \rightarrow B)  \rightarrow (\square A \rightarrow \square B)$

and let's add moreover the reflexivity axiom

**T**: $\square A \rightarrow A$

and the axiom

**5**: $\diamond A \rightarrow \square \diamond A$

How can one then prove the symmetry axiom

**B**: $A \rightarrow \square \diamond A$

from these?

It seems that some transformations need to be done, but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1):

$1. \ \square \neg A \rightarrow \neg A$ ;; by **T**

$2. \ A \rightarrow \neg \square \neg A$ ;; classical tautology (Modus Tollens + $\neg\neg$-elimination) from line $1.$

$3. \ A \rightarrow \diamond A$ ;; definition of $\diamond$ in terms of $\square$, from line $2.$

$4. \ \diamond A \rightarrow \square \diamond A$ ;; by axiom **5**

$5. \ A \rightarrow \square \diamond A$ ;; classical tautology (Hypothetical syllogism), from lines $3.$ and $4.$

Comment: and how do we get the last line?

Comment: what is MT in 2 line?

Comment: @yehehhd made some edits to make everything more explicit and easier to follow

Comment: I'm asking about this late, but still, I came back to this problem and realized that I don't understand how the last line follows from lines 3 and 4 with MP, could you please explain

Comment: @yehehhd I'm so sorry, I incorrectly wrote MP, it should've been 'Hypothetical syllogism' [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism], I've just fixed it now (still, regardless of naming[s], did you understand that it [was an instance of] a classical tautology?)

Comment: But, in fact, we dont have hypothetical syllogism as an axiom in our problem, so to use it, I think, we should prove it

Comment: It's a classical tautology (an intuitionistic theorem, even!) so it should be available to use